# how to forward request to alexa if custom skill cannot answer

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

In short I am looking for **how to configure or add feature to my custom skill so Alexa can answer on behalf of my my skill**.

**Details of my question**,
Let's say I have written a custom skill and sometimes a user may ask a simple question which I haven't handled in my skill since it is more expected to be asked directly to Alexa.
**Example -** 
In case of a smart mirror - *SmartMirror tell me the time*. I am not handling intents of those kind ( time, date etc. ) so it will be more sensible if instead of answering I do not understand that, the custom skill can forward it to Alexa and get an answer from Alexa if available.

Please let me know if you require more details.

Comment: That seems like something Amazon would not allow, as a matter of policy, since it would blur the distinction between Alexa and your skill.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this yet, there's simple no way (no API or functionality) to do it. This is a common issue with skills doing sound output or telling stories where the user asks to modify the volume while in a session with the skill. When that happens these skills have to tell the user that they need to do that from outside the skill (exit the skill first)!